# Mod rewrite - forwarding some QS args in absence of others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rule:

```
#click out to story or provider
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(?:^|&)target=([^&]*))?(?:(?:^|&)ref=([^&]*))?
RewriteRule ^out/([^\/]+)/(item|source)/(\w{11})$ out.php?cntnt_type=$1&item_or_source=$2&id=$3&target=%1&ref=%2
```

Amongst other things, this should allow, and forward, two **optional** query string params: `target` and `ref`.

If I test this with a URL that contains **both** of these params, both get sent.

If, however, one of the params is omitted, neither gets sent.

How can I modify it to allow either param in isolation, rather than only both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (without RewriteCond):

```
RewriteRule ^out/([^\/]+)/(item|source)/(\w{11})$ out.php?cntnt_type=$1&item_or_source=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

[QSA] causes the first query string to be combined without need to test.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. What do the other additions of yours do, namely the `NC` and `L` flags?

Comment: NC is nocase: it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI. And L is last: Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules. All flags here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html